# How to Auto Answer and Dial 9

Tags: twilio

I just bought an Airbnb that requires guests to enter a gate code which then dials my phone number which I have to answer and press 9 several times until the gate opens. I'm looking to automate this process in Twilio Stack Flows.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have no idea what to input into the system to make this work (if it's even possible).

Answer (score 0):

One way you might want to build this is via Twilio Studio (Twilio's low-code solution) and the Say/Play Widget.

Specifically, there's a [Play Digits Configuration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/sayplay#play-digits-configuration) which mimics a keypress, so you can automate the process of pressing 9 several times.